# How to disable Sonarqube Dashboard creation from Users

Tags: sonarqube, dashboard

Could you guide me that how do i can disable dashboard creation options from users in our sonarqube version-5.6.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Users can create all the private dashboards they want. You can only limit the *permission* to globally share dashboards to others.